# Overload recursively based on template parameter

Tags: c++

When playing around with good ol' `c++` I started wondering whether it is possible to overload a template function based on an enclosing template. At the first layer this looks achievable, however, how can this be done recursively? So that the below **pseudo-c++ code**

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

template <typename T> void magic(){
    std::cout << "Called magic<T>" << std::endl;
}

template <typename std::vector<T> > void magic(){
    std::cout << "Called magic<std::vector<T> >" << std::endl;
    magic<T>();
}

template <typename std::map<T,U> > void magic(){
    std::cout << "Called magic<std::map<T,U> >" << std::endl;
    magic<T>();
    magic<U>();
}


int main() {
    magic<std::vector<std::map<std::string,std::vector<int> > > >();
}
```

yields something like:

```sh
Called magic<std::vector<T> >
Called magic<std::map<T,U> >
Called magic<T>
Called magic<std::vector<T> >
Called magic<T>
```

In principle this does not look like it should be impossible because all the type info is available at compile time. The compiler could easily create all required functions since the recursion is bound to stop. And thus the question: **Is this possible? If so, how?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple specialization should do the trick, but bear in mind that you cannot specialize function templates partially, so you'll need an intermediate class template:

```
template <typename> void magic();

template <typename T>
struct Impl 
{
    static void f() { std::cout << "Primary template\n"; }
};

template <typename T, typename A>
struct Impl<std::vector<T, A>>
{
    static void f() { std::cout << "A vector\n"; magic<T>(); }
};

template <typename K, typename T, typename P, typename A>
struct Impl<std::map<K, T, P, A>>
{
    static void f() { std::cout << "A map\n"; magic<K>(); magic<T>(); }
};

template <typename T> void magic() { Impl<T>::f(); }
```

Comment: It is C++11 (because of `>>`), I'm not sure if that matters.

Comment: I knew I forgot about something... Can't decide which answer to accept since both solutions are equal. So I threw a coin, you got lucky :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need **partial template specialization**, that is a template specialization which itself is a template again.

That is not possible with function templates but it is with classes. So the workaround is to create a class template (here called `Magic`) with the specializations. Within that class, a simple (non-template) function is called.

Then, a function `magic` forwards to that class in order to hide that "hack":

[**Live demo** of this code snippet](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7489b8a6df0ddb80)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

// Forward declaration of the magic function:
template <typename> void magic();

// General case:
template <typename T>
struct Magic {
    static void m(){
        std::cout << "Called magic<T>" << std::endl;
    }
};

// Vector case:
template <typename T>
struct Magic<std::vector<T> > {
    static void m(){
        std::cout << "Called magic<std::vector<T> >" << std::endl;
        magic<T>();
    }
};

// Map case:
template <typename T, typename U>
struct Magic<std::map<T,U> > {
    static void m(){
        std::cout << "Called magic<std::map<T> >" << std::endl;
        magic<T>();
        magic<U>();
    }
};

// Implementation of the magic function:
template <typename T>
void magic() {
    std::cout << "Forwarding..." << std::endl;
    Magic<T>::m();
}

int main() {
    magic<std::vector<std::map<std::string,std::vector<int> > > >();
}
```

Comment: I knew I forgot about something... Can't decide which answer to accept since both solutions are equal. So I threw a coin, unfortunately it came up tails. Nevertheless, thanks for the answer! :-)